# How to find the exact value of this number series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^{n}+(-2)^{n}} \frac{(-3)^{n}}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, irrational-numbers

I already know that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^{n}+(-2)^{n}} \frac{(-3)^{n}}{n}$$ is convergent.

```
SumConvergence[((-3)^n/(3^n + (-2)^n) 1/n), n](*True*)
NSum[(1/(3^n + (-2)^n))*((-3)^n/n), {n, 1, Infinity}](*-3.09332855962*)
```

I want to know what to do to get its exact value. If its limit value is an irrational number that can't be expressed, I hope it can be proved.

Comment: Chances are, you're out of luck. I see no reason to think there's a closed form, and little hope of proving that.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you very much, that is to say, the exact value of this limit is an irrational number, but it is difficult to prove.

Comment: That would be my guess, yes.

Comment: "I hope it can be proved". What you hope can be proven? Is it that the limit is an irrational number? Or that it can't be expressed in closed form? Those are two different things.